# How to set the <title> tag for IPython notebook HTML output?

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I'm using an IPython notebook to store mixed documentation/examples for a project. I am using `ipython nbconvert notebook.ipynb` to render HTML output (uses `pandoc` internally). The problem I have is that `nbconvert` insists on giving the HTML output an ugly blank title tag:

```html
<title>[]</title>
```

I've looked through all the options described in `ipython nbconvert --help-all` and can't find anything that will allow me to change the title.

```bash
ipython nbconvert --to html --template full notebook.ipynb
```

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The template which is being used is in:
https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/master/nbconvert/templates/html/full.tpl#L11

In particular, the line I've highlighted defines the html title. This comes from the metadata dictionary (which you can edit with Edit->"Edit notebook metadata" in the notebook itself).

Interestingly though, for me, the title *is* populated by default - it is the name of the notebook file.

Anyway, hope this is helpful.

Comment: Adding "name": "My_notebook_name", in notebook metadata dictionary worked for me ("title" was overwritten by nbconvert to the name of the notebook file).

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: The link should now be https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/main/share/templates/classic/index.html.j2